# rsync + chmod multiple files

Tags: bash, permissions, rsync, chmod

I have a source folder

**source/**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 27773 27773 12 Mar 23 21:41 aws-1                                                                                         
-rw-r--r-- 1 27773 27773 12 Mar 23 21:41 aws-2
```

the destination folder doesn't exist yet. And I try to rsync the 2 aws files into a destination folder. Here is my command:

```
rsync \
--include="aws*" \
--exclude="*" \
-avh --chmod=a=rw "source/." "destination"
```

What I'm trying to do is to rsync the 2 aws files and change their permissions once in the destination folder. After running the command, I got an error and the files are not in the destination folder. Only the folder is created. Here is the error:

```
sending incremental file list                                                                                                          
created directory destination                                                                                                          
rsync: failed to modify permissions on "/home/cg/root/destination/.": Permission denied (13)                                           
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/home/cg/root/destination/aws-1": Permission denied (13)                                        
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/home/cg/root/destination/aws-2": Permission denied (13)                                        
./                                                                                                                                     

sent 88 bytes  received 346 bytes  868.00 bytes/sec                                                                                    
total size is 24  speedup is 0.06                                                                                                      
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]
```

It says permission denied without copying the files. I don't already understand which permission cause problem. My source file and directory seems fine. The created destination folder seems also fine.

PS: I precise my rsync command happens inside a bash script

Comment: why are you adding the `.` to `source/.`  ? also, if `destination` exists you need a trailing slash.

Comment: Have you tried a `sudo`? Example, `sudo chmod a+r *`

Comment: @bistoco removing the `.` doesn't change anything and the `destination` folder doesn't exist yet. @moo_we_all_do after applying chmod to the files in `source/` works but I still have the same error with rsync

Comment: i cannot find any working example for your `--chmod=a=rw` syntax, the closest is [this](http://serverfault.com/a/233586/301323)

Comment: I *suspect* what may be happening is that `rsync` is successfully *removing* execute permission from `destination` - which then prevents it from being accessed to complete the rest of the transfer. Try `--chmod=a=rwX` instead.

Comment: @steeldriver: It works, thanks a lot. But I don't understand why `rsync` needs  execute permission. Copying is not a read/write operation? @bistoco Thanks for having tried to help

Comment: I tried with another file to a different destination directory with the following command `rsync --include="google*" --exclude="*" -avh --chmod=a=rw "source/google-1.json" "destination2/` and it works. weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directories need execute permission in order for processes to access (open) them.

When you use `--chmod=a=rw`, the destination directory gets created but then immediately gets its permissions set to `drw-rw-rw` such that its contents become inaccessible ("`failed to stat`") e.g. given

```
$ tree
.
└── source
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3

1 directory, 3 files
```

then

```
$ rsync --include="file*" --exclude="*" -avh --chmod=a=rw source/ destination/
sending incremental file list
created directory destination
rsync: failed to modify permissions on "/home/steeldriver/destination/.": Permission denied (13)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/home/steeldriver/destination/file1": Permission denied (13)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/home/steeldriver/destination/file2": Permission denied (13)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/home/steeldriver/destination/file3": Permission denied (13)
./

sent 107 bytes  received 502 bytes  1.22K bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

fails because

```
$ ls -dl destination/
drw-rw-rw- 2 steeldriver steeldriver 4096 Mar 23 18:24 destination/
```

so that

```
$ ls -al destination/
ls: cannot access 'destination/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'destination/..': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
```

The solution is to use `--chmod=a=rwX` (or, equivalently, `--chmod=ugo=rwX`)

```
$ rsync --include="file*" --exclude="*" -avh --chmod=ugo=rwX source/ destination/
sending incremental file list
created directory destination
./
file1
file2
file3

sent 224 bytes  received 110 bytes  668.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

where the `X` symbolic mode means

```
execute/search only if the file is  a  directory  or
already  has  execute permission for some use
```

See `man chmod`

Comment: Thx steeldriver. Very good answer and it solved my problem